# jQuery .remove() won't remove dynamic input item

Tags: jquery

I have a file upload section. Adding files triggers the upload and passes back the filename.  That filename is added to a hidden input element in an array. It is also truncated and shown to the user in a `<li>`.

This adds the `<li>`:

```
function addFile(filename, imgName, id) {
    $("#fileGroup ul").append('<li id="file' + id + '" class="list-group-item attachment"><div class="pull-right"><a href="#" onclick="return trash_click(' + id + ')"><i class="btn-icon fa fa-trash"></i></a></div><span>' + filename + '</span></li>');
}
```

This adds the hidden element:

```
$('<input>').attr({
    type: 'hidden',
    name: 'RequestFileName[' + i + ']',
    id: 'RequestFileName[' + i + ']',
    value: imgName
}).appendTo('form');
```

and results in adding:

```
<input type="hidden" name="RequestFileName[1]" id="RequestFileName[1]" value="03b35411-aa77-441c-bde5-2965f0f4db45\Capture1.JPG">
```

Clicking the icon in the `<li>` goes to the function below. This DOES remove the `<li>`, but does NOT effect the added input element:

```
function trash_click(id) 
{
    $('#file' + id).remove();
    $('#RequestFileName[' + id + ']').remove();
    return false;
}
```

At first I thought it may be the array portion that was not allowing the remove, but I tested by using just a simple '#mytest' as the id, but the form elements just won't remove.

Ideas?

Comment: $('#RequestFileName[' + i + ']').remove(); ... put id instead i

Comment: [jQuery Selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/): _"To use any of the meta-characters (such as `!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^``{|}~`) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \\. For example, an element with `id="foo.bar"`, can use the selector `$("#foo\\.bar")`"_

Comment: That was my bad putting the code into the question.  It is actually: $('#RequestFileName[' + id + ']').remove();

Comment: Put an alert or a breakpoint it to see what the value of id is inside the function. I suspect it is the whole id of the item clicked rather than the number of the item.

Comment: you sure the filenames have no white spaces in them

Comment: I do not believe it is in the file naming.  I tested this by adding another element appendto with the name 'myTest'. The element added to the form same as the other ones.  Adding a remove for 'myTest' does NOT remove that either.  I've read something about using the document.on. Not sure how I would apply that in this case?

Comment: Rob - the id is definitely being passed.  Again, even a static name does not work to remove the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the brackets `[` `]` are special characters, selector-wise, so you have to escape them for it to work. The "beauty" of jQuery is it just silently fails, but if you'd try to run that same selector using `document.querySelector` you'd notice there's an error:

```js
document.querySelector('#RequestFileName[1]').value = '1';
```

```html
<input type="text" name="RequestFileName[1]" id="RequestFileName[1]" value="03b35411-aa77-441c-bde5-2965f0f4db45\Capture1.JPG">
```

Here you have it: https://jsfiddle.net/n34rfz51/

Your "solution" worked because you're ignoring them without being aware, you're running a query that looks like `#requestForm input[name='RequestFileName[1]']`. Since the brackets are quotes they act as text and your query works

Other way to escape the value, and keep your main code, would be to escape those brackets with a backslash (`\`). Notice you'll need two of them, since a backslash in a string is also special so you have to escape it

```js
$('#RequestFileName\\[1\\]').val('1');
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<input type="text" name="RequestFileName[1]" id="RequestFileName[1]" value="03b35411-aa77-441c-bde5-2965f0f4db45\Capture1.JPG">
```

Here you have it: https://jsfiddle.net/n34rfz51/1/

So your line would change to:

```
$('#RequestFileName\\[' + id + '\\]').remove();
```

Comment: You are absolutely right.  Thanks for the correct answer.

Comment: Sure, no problem. It's always good to know that kind of tricky things

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.  Apparently because the input element was appended to the form, I had to specifically call out the form to remove it.

```
var request = 'RequestFileName[' + id + ']';
var myRequestFile = $("#requestForm input[name='" + request + "']");
myRequestFile.remove();
return false;
```

Comment: Piyin's answer was actually correct. I found myself a workaround without knowing the best way to do it.